# How do you get a custom grammar loaded into atom?

Tags: atom-editor, grammar

I made a custom grammar for a new language so that I could start writing in it.  I generated the package with the atom package generator and put in in a folder in my Documents folder.  I have checked with `apm links` that atom detects it as a package.  I have the package formatted just like the atom article says (https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/creating-a-grammar/) with `README.md`,`LICENSE`,`package.json`,and `grammars/language.cson` files inside.

It seems like no matter what I do, I can't get the editor to detect it as a grammar that can be used.  Not only does it not apply it to files with the extension specified in the `language.cson` file but I can't even force it with the `Ctrl+Shift+L` grammar selector (it doesn't show up).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you did should be sufficient. Have you checked the console for parsing errors?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It turns out I didn't include a repository link, which is why it wouldn't load.  Once I added that I had a few more issues (invalid regex, needed to run `apm rebuild`) but I was able to get them fixed and now it's working great!